# more than one row returned by subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce

I have a query where i am using a coalesce to select one of the values. However i get an error saying more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. I'm using Postgres v9.3.
My code:

```
 select input1,
 input 2,
 (select (coalesce(tblstuff2.input4, '') || coalesce(tblstuff.input5, ''))
  from tblstuff
  join tblstuff2 on....
  where ...)
input 6,
from..
where...
```

i need the coalesce to add two columns(strings) from the table and show up as one. For ex:if column input 4 was mobile number and input 5 was phone , atleast one of them should turn up.

Comment: The `COALESCE` function doesn't ensure a single value is returned. It provides the first non-null value from the list. From your description, you should be using `coalesce(tblstuff2.input4, tblstuff.input5)`. Your problem causing the error is that the criteria in your `where` clause (in the sub-select) are not specific enough, and more than one row matches.

Comment: I did frame my question slightly wrong. The string_agg logic below worked. But your point on my where clause being not specific enough was also true. A combination of both solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's at least three solutions:

### distinct

```
select distinct (coalesce(tblstuff2.input4, '') || coalesce(tblstuff.input5, ''))
  from tblstuff
  join tblstuff2 on....
  where ...
```

If `join` returns the same values.If not, this doesn't work.

### limit 1

```
select (coalesce(tblstuff2.input4, '') || coalesce(tblstuff.input5, ''))
  from tblstuff
  join tblstuff2 on....
  where ...
  limit 1
```

If `join` returns different values, but You lost one of them.

### string_agg

```
select string_agg(coalesce(tblstuff2.input4, '') || coalesce(tblstuff.input5, ''), ', ')
  from tblstuff
  join tblstuff2 on....
  where ...
```

If `join` returns different values and You want return then all.